# Systematic failure of previously working Word macros

Tags: vba, ms-word

Even a simple Word macro created with "Record Macro" fails with compile error

> "invalid outside procedure".

All other macros that once worked now fail in same way. Example:

```
Sub iAccent()
'
' iAccent Macro
' enter an accented i
'
   Selection.TypeText Text:="í"
End Sub
```

I'm using Word for Mac 16.7.  I'm stumped because all my macros seem OK, previously worked, but now all fail with same compile error.

Comment: The issue is that you have some code **outside the procedure**: Means code that is not in between `Sub` and `End Sub`. Actually that is what your error says. Check it. Actually it shoult highlight the issue while showing the error box.

Comment: Thanks, Peh, but as you can see in the example, there is no code outside the procedure.  No error messages appear at any line in the code in MS Visual Basic.  The problem is that no properly coded macro will compile, all generating the outside procedure message.  Clearly, something rather odd and systematic seems to be at work, not simply an improperly coded macro.  That's why I am so puzzled, and Microsoft help tells me they don't deal with macro problems.  I don't know where to turn.

Comment: Does it happen if you create a brand new Word file and add a macro there? Please test this, because the error message is pretty clear about what the issue is.

Comment: Yes.  I even tried creating a simple macro by using the "Record Macro" route.  It, too, on run immediately generated the same error message.  The code generated was fine, first line "Sub Macro1()", last line "End Sub".  Whatever is going on is something beyond an error in any given macro.  All the several macros I have previously worked fine, and no change has been made in their codes.

Comment: The only thing I can imagine then is a corrupt installation, or any other program interfering with it. Therefore my suggestion is: Test if it works on another computer. If so try to re-install Office.

Comment: Thanks for your attention to my problem, Peh.  I posted earlier--or thought that I had; looks like it didn't register for some reason--my resolution of the problem, which is just the one that you've now suggested.  I should have tried a complete removal and re-installation of Word much more quickly then I did, as it is an obvious move for the kind of problem I encountered.  I think I was too caught up in the forest of macro matters to see the re-installation tree.  Thanks again for your attention.